# Just calculus, the integral = 0 and the argument inside integral = 0?

Tags: calculus, integration

It is really hard for me to make a title to describe my question. Below is my question:

Suppose $f(y-x)$ is a known Gaussian function defined as
$$ f(y-x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \left[-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2} \right], \tag{1}$$
so basically we have $\int f(y-x)dy=1$, where the integral is from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.
Also suppose 
$$\int f(y-x) \left[ g(x) - h(y) \right] dy = 0,  \tag{2}$$
where $g(x)$ and $h(y)$ are two unknown functions of variable $x$ and $y$, respectively and the integral is also from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Can we get the conclusion that $g(x)-h(y)=0$ (or equivalently $g(x)=h(y)=c$, c is a constant)? If yes, how to prove? If not, any counter example? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Thanks to @Danu and @Ian, this claim is incorrect. However, anyone knows what general statement can we make for $g(x)-h(y)$? Thanks.**

Comment: Counterexample: $g(x)-h(y)=y-x$

Comment: You are right... Thanks.

Comment: Your equation says nothing more and nothing less than $g(x)=\mathbb{E}(h(Y))$ where $Y$ is a $N(x,1)$ variable. Thus for any $h$ such that $\mathbb{E}(h(Y))$ exists, there is a unique $g$ which satisfies your equation for every $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $g(x) \equiv 0$, this is just the expectation of $-h(Y)$ where $Y$ is a $N(x,1)$ random variable.